# What is the difference between :: and -> operators in php?

Tags: php, oop, class

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)
>   [In PHP, whats the difference between :: and -> ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173501/in-php-whats-the-difference-between-and)

When you try to access property of method inside class whats the difference between :: and -> and is there full reference of operators related to object oriented programming in php somewhere?

Answer (score 7):

The `::` is for static properties and methods, e.g.

```
 MyClass::create();
```

The `->` is for when you have an object instantiated from the class, e.g.

```
$myObject = new MyClass;
$myObject->create();
```

Answer (score 2):

When using `::` you can access a Class method statically without creating an instance of the class, something like:

```
Class::staticMethod();
```

You would use `->` on an instance of a Class, something like:

```
$class = new Class();
$class->classMethod();
```

Comment: unline drewm response, i got this one thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's the difference between **static** and **dynamic** properties and methods.

Observe this piece of code to appreciate the difference:

```
class MyClass {

    protected $myvar = 0;
    public static  $othervar = "test";
    public function start($value)
    {
         // because this is not static, we need an instance.
         // because we have an instance, we may access $this
         $this->myvar = $value;

         // although we may still access our static variable:
         echo self::$othervar;
    }


    static public function myOtherFunction ($myvar)
    {
        // its a static function, so we're not able to access dynamic properties and methods ($this is undefined)

        // but we may access static properties
        self::$overvar = $myvar;
    }
}
```

**Literature for your conveinience:**

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php
- [What are static and dynamic variables / methods in OOP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417438/what-are-static-and-dynamic-variables-methods-in-oop)